# File as a single and married for remaining months

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I was single in Jan 2020 and got married in Feb 2020. So is there something like filing a single for one month and then file as jointly for the remaining months? I was in the same state all time.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd *want* to file as single? You can file as married in the year you get married.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your filing status is based on whatever your status is at the end of the year. If you are married on December 31, 2020, then you will file as Married Filing Jointly (or Married Filing Separately) on your 2020 tax return.

For details, see the [Filing Status section](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm140693675306592) of the Form 1040 instructions).

You can only have one filing status for the entire tax return. It cannot be split.

Comment: This is also true for children, have them at the end of the year and they count for the entire year.

Comment: One small exception: if you are married and your spouse dies, and you don't remarry by the end of the year (and who would?!), you can file MFJ for that (whole) year. @HartCO: you can select the date of your wedding exactly, and maybe even a friendly divorce, but doing so for childbirth is harder